# How to copy text of alert box

Tags: javascript

I write the path of a document into the alert box via using below code.

```
var oArg = new Object();
oArg.Document = $(t).attr("path") + str + "/" + $(t).attr("name");
alert(oArg.Document);
```

Assume that message is : "`documents/files/img/stack.jpg`"

I only want to copy this text with a button. For Chrome Ctrl + C is ok for it but for IE, Ctrl + C copies everything at the alertbox.

How can I copy only the message with using a button?

Ctrl + C works like below:

- Chrome - Works perfectly.
- Internet Explorer - Works, but you get extra text. The caption and OK button text is also copied, along with a bunch of dashes. This is almost never what you want.
- Firefox - Doesn't work at all You must select the text before you can copy it.

Comment: I would prefer to use `console.log` :)

Answer (score 89, accepted):

What you can do is to prompt the user with the text and ask them to copy it. As such:

```
prompt("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter", oArg.Document);
```

Because if you supply a text to the prompt it automatically gets selected. Does this suit you?

Comment: Good solution, how can I close that prompt screen and the opener window with ok button in prompt screen?

Comment: You listen for the return value of the prompt. `if (prompt("Blah bla?")){ doStuff(); }`

Comment: nice trick thanks, wouldn't use it for production because it's terrible UI/UX, but works for me :D

Answer (score 20):

When ever the alert message box appears with the text message , just press **CTRL+ C** and your message will be copied, then you can paste it anywhere you want , no need to write it or using any other method to get the text.

Comment: As mentioned in the questioner a simple ctrl+c doesn't works in all browsers.

Answer (score 16):

I've found that, in Chrome at least, the alert box text is in fact selectable -- *when the text does not contain any line-breaks* (ie. "\n").

I don't know why this is the case, but I've had to use this trick before for quick selection prompts. (you could also use `prompt("please press ctrl+c to copy the text below", "text to copy")`, but that usually looks worse)

Comment: I noticed that if you have another function in the alert, (i.e. `JSON.stringify()`, `btoa()`), you can place the `\n` in there and text can then be selected.