# Javascript - <a href></a> inside alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I' curisous. Is it possible to put link inside javascript alert ? For example: http://example.com. Thank you very much

Comment: You cannot put a link in an `alert()` message.

Comment: Alerts are very bad for UI anyway since they are disruptive. Use a modal dialog instead.

Answer (score 7):

`alert()` only supports text strings. No HTML will be rendered. Quoting from [the MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.alert):

> - `message` is an optional string of text you want to display in the alert dialog, or, alternatively, an object that is converted into a string and displayed.

Use a custom modal (popup) instead.

Answer (score 1):

No it's not possible to provide a clickable link inside a alert.
You could however use a prompt ([as I showed in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591559/how-to-copy-text-of-alert-box/17591662#17591662)) to prompt the user to copy an URL and go to that link.

Like this:

```
prompt("Please copy this URL and paste into your address-bar", "http://example.com/page/visit");
```

Otherwise your only call is to make a custom dialog. You can take a look at [jQuery UI's popular implementations](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/).